# How to use GetJointActuatorIndices() correctly?

Tags: drake

I'm learning Drake C++ and trying simulating an Allegro Hand with a WAM arm in Drake. I'm trying using the example code about controlling the Allegro Hand in which [the actuators need to be configured](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/2042a965043457d59e5f6ae9780bf84d59efc523/examples/allegro_hand/joint_control/allegro_single_object_simulation.cc#L168C3-L169C65) using

`for (JointActuatorIndex actuator_index(0); actuator_index < plant.num_actuators(); ++actuator_index) {...}`

However, I added other models in `plant` so I need to specify the actuators I configure. I tried using GetJointActuatorIndices() based on [the example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/5a96aa5ef346a3874efa6fb045d56c9d0bc53f47/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h#L417) as

`for (JointActuatorIndex joint_actuator_index : plant.GetJointActuatorIndices(model_hand[0])) {...}`

where I pre-defined

`const auto& model_hand = parser.AddModels(...);`

But it gives error as

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 2) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

How could I fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your approach seems correct.
To be clear, the call to GetJointActuatorIndices is returning a list of JointActuatorIndex, but subsequent calls which use that index are throwing the error?  (it's not the actual call to GetJointActuatorIndices that is throwing the error?)

Comment: @RussTedrake Thank you and you are right! I didn't set the transmissions in the URDF file of my robot model and that actually caused the error.